US live action movie from the 90s with cheesy humor
This is a movie I saw in the US around the mid 90s, most likely from US origin. I'd like to check how (good or) bad it was if someone helps with the title.
The thing I remember best from it was a very cheesy line : "I heard you coming this time".
So let me elaborate a bit : the plot is something like a rather muscular guy (but probably not Arnold or Sylvester-like though), possibly a detective (but not sure) who probably does martial arts (kung fu ? karate ?) somehow rescues a woman (how original :-) from bad guys (can't remember who or why).
At some point she's in her (or possibly rather his, for her protection ?) flat (or maybe instead a loft, with the typical large lift of former warehouses/factories ?) and he's there and she didn't hear him arrive.
Then later in the movie they make love and she says "I heard you coming this time".
I'm not 100% sure, for another scene which may come from another movie watched at the same period : the hero and a similar guy (rather muscular etc...) are stuck in a car being crushed in a car junkyard press, they manage to escape the car and imminent death by pushing the roof off with their legs.

Showdown in Little Tokyo from 1991. From IMDb:

Detective Chris Kenner [Dolph Lundgren] was orphaned as a child as his father was in the service and was killed and lived in Japan. Now he is on the trail of ruthless Yakuza leader named Yoshido, who helped establish a small Japanese area in Los Angeles and is now running a drug ring disguised as a brewery. However, Kenner must team up with a Japanese-American detective named Johnny Murata [Brandon Lee], and he also must protect a witness named Minako [Tia Carrere] who would testify against Yoshido. 

Kenner tells Minako at some point, “You won’t hear me coming”. Later on they have sex and she says, “That time, I heard you coming.” Kenner and Murata also manage to escape a car as it's being crushed at a junkyard at some point. Here's the trailer:




Well that was fast... and I guess that's it, thanks. I'll try to find the movie. Could it be also the answer to http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19093/movie-about-rescuing-an-asian-woman-from-a-gang ?

I don't think so, but then again, it's been ages... Glad you found it.

I was thinking "They Live."
